# Converting symbolic expression to function handle in Matlab R2013b

Tags: matlab, equation

I am struggling to convert a function, which I require for my civil engineering project, from symbolic expression. I need to use `fzero` to find the root of the function. Here `H` should be the variable and I need to find out the value of `H`. The function goes like

```
function x_c = f_x_c(s,H0,VA,Lo,qc,EAo,NF,Sj,Fj)

if (s < 0) || (s > Lo)
    disp('The value of s is invalid')
    disp(['s = ' num2str(s)]);
    return
end


C1 = H/qc;
if NF == 0
    n = 0;
    sn = 0;
    sum_Fj = 0;
end


if NF >= 1
    Sj_Q = [0; Sj; Lo];
    %Determine n and sn if 0 <= s < Lo:
    if s < Lo
        STOP = 0;
        k = 0;
        while STOP == 0
            k = k + 1;
            if (s >= Sj_Q(k,1)) && (s < Sj_Q((k + 1),1))
                STOP = 1;
            end
        end
        n = k - 1;
        sn = Sj_Q(k,1);
    end
    %Determine n and sn if s = Lo:
    if s == Lo
        n = NF;
        sn = Sj(NF,1);
    end
    sum_Fj = sum(Fj(1:n,1));
end


x_c = (H/EAo)*s;
x_c = x_c + C1*asinh((qc*s - VA + sum_Fj)/H) + ...
    - C1*asinh((qc*sn - VA + sum_Fj)/H);


for j = 1:n
    sk = Sj_Q((j + 1),1);
    sk_1 = Sj_Q(j,1);
    sum_Fj = sum(Fj(1:(j - 1)));


    x_c = x_c + ...
        + C1*asinh((qc*sk - VA + sum_Fj)/H) + ...
        - C1*asinh((qc*sk_1 - VA + sum_Fj)/H);

end
```

I want to use this `f_x_c.m` file in the main file where I will find the roots of this equation. 
Could someone guide me how I can do that?

I have tried doing it using the following code but I wasn't successful.

```
if (s < 0) || (s > Lo)
    disp('The value of s is invalid')
    disp(['s = ' num2str(s)]);
    return
end

C1 = @(H) (H/qc);
if NF == 0
    n = 0;
    sn = 0;
    sum_Fj = 0;
end


if NF >= 1
    Sj_Q = [0; Sj; Lo];
    %Determine n and sn if 0 <= s < Lo:
    if s < Lo
        STOP = 0;
        k = 0;
        while STOP == 0
            k = k + 1;
            if (s >= Sj_Q(k,1)) && (s < Sj_Q((k + 1),1))
                STOP = 1;
            end
        end
        n = k - 1;
        sn = Sj_Q(k,1);
    end
    %Determine n and sn if s = Lo:
    if s == Lo
        n = NF;
        sn = Sj(NF,1);
    end
    sum_Fj = sum(Fj(1:n,1));
end


x_c =@(H) (H/EAo)*s;
x_c =@(H) (x_c(H) + (C1(H))*asinh((qc*s - VA + sum_Fj)/H) + ...
    - (C1(H))*asinh((qc*sn - VA + sum_Fj)/H));


for j = 1:n
    sk = Sj_Q((j + 1),1);
    sk_1 = Sj_Q(j,1);
    sum_Fj = sum(Fj(1:(j - 1)));


    x_c =@(H) (x_c(H) + ...
        + C1(H)*asinh((qc*sk - VA + sum_Fj)/H) + ...
        - C1(H)*asinh((qc*sk_1 - VA + sum_Fj)/H));

end
```

**Edit:**

I want to solve the following equation in the main file:

```
equation = f_x_c(inext_length, H0, vertical_reaction, inext_length, qc, EAo, NF, hanger_arc_length, point_hanger_force) + 1400;
% Whatever equation f_x_c returns, I have to add another number to it(like here it is 1400), then solve this equation using fzero.
```

So, in the main file, I wrote like:

```
equation = @(H) f_x_c(inext_length, H0, vertical_reaction, inext_length, qc, EAo, NF, hanger_arc_length, point_hanger_force);

equation = @(H) (equation(H) + 1400);
answer = fsolve(equation, H0);
```

Comment: what about matlabFunction:http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html

Comment: @Benoit_11 I have Matlab R2013b. This function doesn't work in this version, I guess.

Comment: Where's the attempted call to `fzero`?  What function are you trying to solve?  I don't actually see any symbolic math.  Do you just want to solve the entire first function?  Then use @f_x_c.  But I also notice in that function that `H` is undefined.  The parameter is `H0`.

Comment: @Peter I have edited the question and added that how I am calling `fzero` in the main file. Can you please recheck?

Comment: @Peter `H` is the variable which I want the  value of, whereas `H0` is a constant. I am not using the value of `H0` in the function at present, but that would be used later.

Comment: But your function won't run as it is.  You're using the value of H, but it's not defined anywhere.  I think you meant to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Peter How should be the function run then? `H` is an unknown. I want to solve the equation to get the value of `H`. One thing that I know is that the value of `H` would be around than `H0`. SO, I want that value of `H` which is nearest to `H0`.

Comment: But it's still a function of H.  Think about this: find the zero of "f(x) = x + 2".  `x` is unknown, but the function is still in terms of `x`.  First write the function that gives you a value for any value of H, THEN solve it using fzero, which will specify the initial guess of H0.

Comment: @IndiaSlaver Have you tested your f_x_c function? I don't see definition of H

Comment: @Kostya Well, if I write `syms H` right after defining the function (in the second line, that is), it gives me an equation in which variable is `H`.

Comment: You don't want symbolic math here.  You just want a normal numeric function that returns a value for any value of the input, so that fzero can call it a bunch to solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mock answer to your question probably looks like

```
function x_c = f_x_c(H,A,B,C,D)
    x_c = H*A;
    x_c = x_c + B*asinh(C/H) - B*asinh(D/H);
end
```

and a call to solver is

```
H = fzero(@(H)(f_x_c(H,1,1,1,1)+1400),1);
```

Comment: You know, I am new to Matlab. I only use it for my civil engineering problems. I don't really know what function handles are. And so, I spent 2 days in trying to convert symbolics to function handles, but all unsuccessfully. And you did it so easily. Thanks a lot, man. I would really be grateful to you.