# Newton's method roots on Matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions, newtons-method

I am not so much experiences with Matlab. I just need it for the sake of solving some lengthy non-linear equations. Instead of using `fzero`, I wanna use Newton-Raphson's to solve the equation.

`newton.m` file contains the following code.

```
function [ x, ex ] = newton( f, df, x0, tol, nmax )

    if nargin == 3
        tol = 1e-4;
        nmax = 1e1;
    elseif nargin == 4
        nmax = 1e1;
    elseif nargin ~= 5
        error('newton: invalid input parameters');
    end

    x(1) = x0 - (f(x0)/df(x0));
    ex(1) = abs(x(1)-x0);
    k = 2;
    while (ex(k-1) >= tol) && (k <= nmax)
        x(k) = x(k-1) - (f(x(k-1))/df(x(k-1)));
        ex(k) = abs(x(k)-x(k-1));
        k = k+1;
    end

end
```

And in the main file, I have called this function as follows:

```
ext_H = newton( exp(x) + x^3, diff(exp(x) + x^3), 9, 0.5*10^-5, 10);
```

When I run this function, it gives me the following error.

```
Error using sym/subsref (line 9)
Error using maplemex
Error, (in MTM:-subsref) Array index out of range

Error in newton (line 37)
    x(1) = x0 - (f(x0)/df(x0));

Error in main (line 104)
ext_H = newton( exp(x) + x^3, diff(exp(x) + x^3), 9, 0.5*10^-5, 10);
```

Could anyone please help me to get through this?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason not to use MAtlab's fzero/fsolve?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Matlab's fsolve (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) with a couple of options

```
x0 = 9;
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt','TolFun',5*10^-6,'MaxIter',100);
x = fsolve(@(x)(exp(x) + x^3), x0,options);
```

or just fzero (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fzero.html) which implements BD algorithm

```
x = fzero(@(x)(exp(x) + x^3), x0);
```

Comment: Can you please look at this post of mine?

Comment: Do you mean your question above?

Comment: No, forgive me. I forgot to paste the link. Please look at this post from me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251770/converting-symbolic-expression-to-function-handle-in-matlab-r2013b?noredirect=1#comment43017237_27251770